# Count matrix memory consumption

Tags: matlab

Is there any Matlab function that returns the amount of DRAM memory a matrix consumes? Of course there is the classic way, correct me if I am wrong, `MemSize = numel(myMatrix)*BytesPerElement` where  `BytesPerElement = 4` if we work with double or  `BytesPerElement = 1` if we work with single. Of course if there is not such function one can suggests his own way to count memory in Bytes. Mega Bytes or Giga Bytes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to use the programmatic form of [WHOS](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/whos.html):

```
>> x = rand(1024);
>> w = whos

w = 

      name: 'x'
      size: [1024 1024]
     bytes: 8388608
     class: 'double'
    global: 0
    sparse: 0
   complex: 0
   nesting: [1x1 struct]
persistent: 0
```

Comment: Nice it returns a structure with all variables inside! Thank you!